# Fastest way to count elements of MySQL table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to count numbers of rows of a table with 3.5M of rows:

```
DESC rp_uploadFile;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| rp_uploadFileID     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| rp_uploadFileTypeID | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| rp_clientID         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| rp_facilityID       | mediumint(4) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| rp_groupID          | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| rp_userID           | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rp_dateUpload       | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rp_extensionCode    | varchar(5)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rp_fileName         | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| rp_folderID         | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rp_isActive         | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| rp_type             | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0,000 sec)
```

with theses indexes :

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM rp_uploadFile;
+---------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name              | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+---------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| rp_uploadFile |          0 | PRIMARY               |            1 | rp_uploadFileID     | A         |     3315091 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rp_uploadFile |          1 | rp_uploadFileTypeID   |            1 | rp_uploadFileTypeID | A         |          24 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rp_uploadFile |          1 | rp_clientID           |            1 | rp_clientID         | A         |     1105030 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rp_uploadFile |          1 | rp_groupID            |            1 | rp_groupID          | A         |         216 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| rp_uploadFile |          1 | rp_fileName           |            1 | rp_fileName         | A         |     3315091 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rp_uploadFile |          1 | rp_uploadFileTypeID_2 |            1 | rp_facilityID       | A         |        4818 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| rp_uploadFile |          1 | rp_uploadFileTypeID_2 |            2 | rp_uploadFileTypeID | A         |       14351 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rp_uploadFile |          1 | rp_uploadFileTypeID_2 |            3 | rp_isActive         | A         |       14733 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| rp_uploadFile |          1 | rp_isActive           |            1 | rp_isActive         | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+---------------+------------+-----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
9 rows in set (0,000 sec)
```

This is very long :

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `rp_uploadFile`;
+----------+
| COUNT(1) |
+----------+
|  3299571 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0,688 sec)
```

and this query with a rowCount is longest

```
SELECT rp_uploadFileID FROM `rp_uploadFile`;
....
3299577 rows in set (1,128 sec)
```

This is great :

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'rp_uploadFile';
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| Name          | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows    | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment | Max_index_length | Temporary |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| rp_uploadFile | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 3315119 |            124 |   411959296 |               0 |    723451904 |  12582912 |        5085809 | 2023-01-05 14:52:07 | 2023-10-16 13:54:33 | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |                0 | N         |
+---------------+--------+---------+------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,001 sec)
```

but I don't love to use this kind of system query (SHOW TABLE STATUS) for business.

Do you have an idea for count these rows faster ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The term is "row" or "record" (or even "relation tuple") - not "element".

Comment: Your `SHOW TABLE STATUS` query indicates `3315119` rows but your other queries indicate `3299571` and `3299577` rows - they all contradict each other.

Comment: What it means ?

Comment: @Dai No. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-table-status.html ***Rows** - The number of rows. Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is **an approximation**, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40% to 50%. In such cases, use SELECT COUNT(\*) to obtain an accurate count.*

Comment: ok i'm in InnoDB

Answer (score 2):

The TABLE_ROWS is only an estimate for InnoDB tables. It's not a simple answer what the number of rows is, in a storage engine that supports transaction isolation.

- Is it the number of rows including uncommitted rows?
- Is it the number of rows committed?
- Is it the number of rows visible to your transaction (if you use repeatable-read)? Or visible to another transaction? Or is it all committed rows (as though using read-committed), even though your transaction can't see all of those rows?

So the INFORMATION_SCHEMA (or SHOW TABLE STATUS) is not the right place to get a row count.

This also points out why it takes a long time to do a COUNT(*) query against InnoDB. It has to evaluate every row in the table to see if that row belongs in your transaction's view of the database. This is the downside of using an ACID database.

If you need to access the count with high performance, you'll need to keep track of the count as the result of the aggregate query, and store that value somewhere else, like another table, or an in-memory cache.

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/44599635/20860 but it is sufficiently different that I didn't vote to close it as a duplicate. I have copied my own answer from the other question.

Comment: Thanks @bill

So, other than storing the number of rows in another table and updating it each time (i.e. several thousand times a day), there's nothing faster than a simple COUNT(*) or COUNT(1) ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If you search for similar questions, it's a frequent question for users of InnoDB, or any other database that implements transactions.